# In-place Python dictionary inverse

Tags: python, dictionary, swap, in-place

The task that I wanted to see if possible to solve is, swapping key,value pairs of a dictionary (in Python), with an in-place calculation, **without additional data-structures** (Only a constant number of extra variables). It seems rather impossible (in a finite world), but I'm open to hear suggestions on solving it.

I've seen a few posts about in-place dictionary inverse in python, and I've found one common thing between all of the solutions.
The following dictionary won't be properly inversed:

```
dict = {'b':'a','a':'c','c':123}
```

The reason for that is, when swapping the first argument, we overwrite 'a''s actual value (The values are unique, the keys are unique, but that doesn't mean there isn't a value that is the same as an already existing key)

**NOTES:**

1) The dictionary given as an example has hashable values.

2) The key/values can be of any data-type. Not necessarily strings.

I'd love to hear ways to solve it, I've thought of one but it only works if we have infinite memory, which obviously is not true.

**EDIT:**

1) My Idea was, changing the dictionary such that I add a constant number of underscores ("_") to the beginning of each key entry. The number of underscores is determined based on the keys, if some key has X underscores, I'll add X+1 underscores (max_underscores_of_key_in_prefix+1).
To work around objects in the keys, I'll make a wrapper class for that.
I have tried my best explaining my intuition, but I am not sure this is practical.

2) @Mark Ransom's solution works perfectly, but if anyone has an other algorithmic solution to the problem, I'd still love to hear it out!
I mark this question as solved because it is solved, but again, other solutions are more than welcome :-)

Comment: What makes you think this is even possible, given the number of constraints you've placed on the solution?

Comment: I don't see how that would be possible - in the general case, some given dictionaries cannot be inverted this way, as there is no value that isn't a key to start with. Also I don't see how this meets the practical/answerable requirement.

Comment: I said, "I don't know if it is possible". I was able to think of a solution, given infinitely large memory size. I wanted to know if it is possible, and if so, I'd love to hear a solution. I haven't stated that it is possible, simply because I don't know if it is possible myself.

Comment: Could you explain why something like `{v: k for k, v in dict.iteritems()}` doesn't meet the requirements?

Comment: @bphi because it's not in place, you're creating another data structure.

Comment: @bphi because that isn't in-place.

Comment: @bphi 
This is creating a new dictionary and not modifying the already-existing one

Comment: What is the purpose of doing this in place? Is it a memory issue? There's non-in-place methods that could be memory constant. (Or very nearly.)

Comment: @DylanLawrence This is an algorithmic question. I wanted to know if doing such thing is even possible with the given constraints. 
I've added a solution I've had in mind, but again, it feels kind of absurd..

Comment: @Jonathan. Your solution seems quite possible. What actual issue are you experiencing at that point? Is your question one of aesthetics?

Comment: Also, what do you do with unhashable values?

Comment: Define "in place". Your proposed solution involves doubling the size of the dict, creating many new objects, and almost certainly triggering a rehashing.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I mean, it feels like kind of a bad solution doesn't it?
I wanted to know if there are any other solutions (maybe more elegant ones) to the problem honestly

Comment: @user2357112
By in-place I mean, you can modify the dictionary how-ever you want, as long as you end-up with the "same" (Like, same dict object, not a new one created..) dictionary. My proposed solution deletes the older values, so it's not doubling

Comment: Is the problem additional data structures at all, or additional storage? You could make a solution that destroys the input `dict` as it constructs a new temporary `dict`, then (to get in-place behavior) destroys the temporary `dict` while reinserting into the `input` dict. That would get (roughly) fixed memory costs; at any given time, only one key/value mapping would be stored (in one of two `dict`s) for a given pair. Huge waste of effort in any scenario where `tmp = {v: k for k, v in mydict.iteritems()}; mydict.clear(); mydict.update(tmp)` is an option, but it's possible.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Your solution involves a new dictionary which is not allowed :( but that's something I didn't think of, nice! (The problem is data structures at all)

Comment: What about dicts like `d = {1: 2, 3: 2}`?  What is `inverse(d)[2]`?

Comment: @Jonathan: That's why I asked. It's two `dict`s, but the combined underlying memory requirements would (very roughly, given oversizing of `dict`s) correspond to that of the original input at all times. If *any* additional data structure is verboten, this sounds contrived to the point of ridiculousness.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Values have to be distinct, otherwise an inverse function does not exist (because this is not an injective function when 2 inputs go to the same output, and the inputs differ)

Comment: @ShadowRanger I agree, and my solution feels kind of un-practical too. But I am open to ideas, that's why I decided to ask here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously for this to be possible, both keys and values must be hashable. This means that none of your keys or values can be a `list`. We can take advantage of this to know which dictionary elements have been already processed.

Since you can't iterate and modify a dictionary at the same time, we must start over every time we swap a key/value. That makes this very slow, an O(n^2) operation.

```
def invert_dict(d):
    done = False
    while not done:
        done = True
        for key, val in d.items():
            if isinstance(val, list):
                if len(val) > 1:
                    d[key] = [val[1]]
                    val = val[0]
            else:
                del d[key]
            if not isinstance(val, list):
                if val in d:
                    d[val] = [d[val], key]
                else:
                    d[val] = [key]
                done = False
                break
    for key, val in d.items():
        d[key] = val[0]
```

Comment: Why isn't a list an option of a value?
If it is the case, then the solution is obvious. But I don't see a reason for this to be the case, can you please explain yourself?

Comment: @Jonathan a list isn't hashable, so it can't be used as a dictionary key. Since the goal is to swap keys and values, any value that can't be hashed will cause the swap to fail.

Comment: Fair enough :) 
Good to know!
If there is an other algorithmic solution to the problem, I'd love to hear them. Even though this is good enough =)